# How to add a "Load More" button to bottom of listbox results?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

Hello I'm making a call to a web service that returns results in pages. These results are bound to a listbox in which they are then displayed. I would like to add a "See More" results button to the bottom of the listbox when they scroll to the bottom. Any resources or suggestions on how to accomplish this are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example: [How to add a Control at the end of Items of a ListBox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/windowsphone7series/thread/cdf2716d-0ceb-4c03-9e26-cbe9f53328d8).

This is simplified version of standard template of `ListBox`:

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" 
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}">
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

You can wrap `<ItemsPresenter />` with `StackPanel`, this will allow you to place any content to the scrollable area before or after list items.

Comment: I followed that and it worked. But how can I handle this button? I want to get it in the code-behind... http://stackoverflow.com/q/7705216/340760

Comment: Doing this will break the `ListBox`'s Virtualization though.

Comment: @Xin so how to load more efficiently ?

Comment: @Yamamoto Please take a look at this question I asked a while ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489508/wp7-add-a-load-more-button-at-the-end-of-listbox-without-losing-virtualization No one has given a good answer yet but I think what I suggested in the question should work.

Comment: @Yamamoto, someone actually just gave my question the right answer. :)