# Add a Load More Button at the end of ListBox without losing Virtualization?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

I know by editing the `ListBox`'s default style like this, I can have a `Button` at the very end of the `ListBox`.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ...> 
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsPresenter />
        <Button />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, doing this will break the `ListBox`'s Virtualization and the rendering time becomes really long.

All I can think of is,

1. Create a dummy item and add it to the end of my item collection in
   the viewmodel, and have a `Visibility` property in the dummy object called **ButtonGridVisibility** and set it to `Visibility.Visible`.
2. In my `ListBox`'s `ItemTemplate`, have two `Grids`. One displays
   the normal item layout, the other displays the *Load More* `Button`.
   Then toggle their `Visibility` based on **ButtonGridVisibility** property.

This might work but I just wonder if there is any easier/better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old post but in case some people stumble upon this:

There is a LongListSelector control [available out of the box in WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or as part of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) for WP7 which supports this scenario quite neatly. If you want to add specific content after the last item (or before the first item), you can simply set the ListFooter or ListHeader of the control. You can put any content inside and this content will be scrolled accordingly, together with the rest of the items.

So for WP7 this would look like this:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
        <Grid>
            <Button />
        </Grid>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

where `toolkit` is `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

Comment: Ahhh... I wish I knew this a year ago! Thanks a lot Karel!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of extra features these days that can help with this scenario.  One of them is the addition of additional visual states on the ScrollViewer added "HorizontalCompression" and "VerticalCompression" visual state groups.  By making use of these and hooking into the `CurrentStateChanging` event, you can load more items as you need to.

Full details of how to implement this can be found on the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Performance Team Blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, actually I am aware of this, however I don't want the `ListBox` to automatically load more data when it scrolls to the end. I think having a button there is clearer to the user.