# Change Content of a ListFooterTemplate of LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Follow -up to the answer of this question :[Add a Load More Button at the end of ListBox without losing Virtualization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489508/add-a-load-more-button-at-the-end-of-listbox-without-losing-virtualization/15929639#15929639)

With this example :

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<toolkit:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnReadMore" Content="ReadMore"/>
</Grid>
</toolkit:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
```

Is there a way to change his Content by the C# ? (= "ReadMore" and when the itemsource=0 "go back") thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the value of the `Content` property to some ViewModel property. This is the best way IMHO:

You would also bind the `Command` property to some ViewModel command and this will ensure that you correctly set the caption and handle the result.

But beware, you are not supposed to have a button saying "Go Back" which, when pressed, acts as a hardware back button. You are not supposed to emulate such system functionality.

Comment: ok thank for your help, but I don't use MVVM in my project :/ Or is it possible to have two ListFooterTemplate and change it by the C# ?

Comment: If you are not using MVVM, start using it ;) You can always manually change `Content` in the code behind whenever you determine you need to do so. You can also declare two different Footer templates in resources and change them on the fly.