# LongListSelector ItemsPresenter not showing items

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm developing a WP8 app.

I have a LongListSelector that shows items fetched from a web service.
When the user reaches the end of the list there must be a "Load more" button at the bottom to inovke the web service and get more items.

The list has a style like this to show the button:

```
<Style x:Key="DenouncesDistanceList" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                            <Button x:Name="LoadMoreToList" Click="LoadMoreToList_Click" >Load moremás</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When running the app like this the phone shows the button but never shows the items.
If I take out the style property on the LongListSelector declaration the items are shown but on a never ending scroll that repeats the items.

This are the definitions of the LongListSelector (with and without the style property):

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LisByDistanceListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ReportListDataTemplate}" Margin="0,0,-24,0" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsByDistance}" Width="480" Height="476" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource DenouncesDistanceList}" />

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LisByDistanceListBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ReportListDataTemplate}" Margin="0,0,-24,0" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsByDistance}" Width="480" Height="476" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Before using the LongListSelector I was using a ListBox with the same Style and the same ItemTemplate and everything worked well until too many items were loaded forcing the app to rise an OutOfMemoryException.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, solved this using the LongListSelector.ListFooter like stated on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432573/2686243